# Deadlock with a thread shut down

Tags: multithreading, visual-c++

I am writing a dialog based multithreading application with Visual C++. It has several views.

OnInitialUpdate function I start a working thread like this:

```
pThread = AfxBeginThread(MultiThread, this, THREAD_PRIOIRITY_NORMAL, 0 CREATE_SUSPENDED, NULL);
pThread->m_bAutoDelete = false;
pThread->ResumeThread();
```

OnDestroy function I have

```
eventKill.SetEvent();
WaitForSingleObject(pHread->m_hThread, INFINITE);
delete pThread
```

MultiThread function has

```
...
while (WaitForSingleObject(pView->eventKill.m_hObject, 0) != WAIT_OBJECT_0)
{
    ...
    pView->InvalidateRect(rect);
    pView->UpdateWindow();
    Sleep(100);
}
return 0;
```

This usually shuts down nicely, but I have found one exception. I have this thread and its view running. There is another view which is currently on top and the thread view is partially under it. If I close the thread view by pressing directly its close button without first making this thread view the topmost window, the program deadlocks in WaitForSingleObject(pThread->m_hThread, INFINITE). If I do not use UpdateWindow there will be no deadlocks. If I make the thread view the topmost before pressing the close button, there are no problems either. So why the deadlock?

Answer (score 2):

The UpdateWindow() function can only complete until the thread that owns the window has dispatched the WM_PAINT event.  That cannot happen here, the UI thread is blocked in the WaitForSingleObject call.  That call can never complete, the thread is blocked on UpdateWindow.  Deadlock.

This kind of code is going to eat you alive if you don't observe the stone cold hard rules of threading with a user interface.  Neither user32 nor gdi are thread-safe.  The UI thread can *never* block without pumping messages.  You have to use MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx().  A worker thread should *never* directly use any API functions that affect a window.  Only the system messages are automatically marshaled, use PostMessage() instead so that the UI thread can do the updates.

Answer (score 0):

I did not know UpdateWindow keeps waiting WM_PAINT. I guess also InvalidateRect is not thread safe even when it does not wait WM_PAINT. I changed my worker thread to use PostMessage. Thank you!

Comment: Better use comments to reply to someone's answer. :)

Comment: This isn't an answer.  Close your question by marking the answer.  Big check mark next to my post.